# Change order in filenames in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

I need to rename a bunch of files in a specific folder. They all end with date and time, like for example "hello 2019-05-22 1310.txt" and I want the date and time for each file to be first so I can sort them. With my code I get an error and it wont find my dir where all files are located. What is wrong with the code?

```
import os
import re
import shutil

dir_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Testfiles' 

comp = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if '.' in file:
        index = [i for i, v in enumerate(file,0) if v=='.'][-1]
        name = file[:index]
        ext = file[index+1:]
    else:
        ext=''
        name = file
    data = comp.findall(name)  
    if len(data)!=0:
        date= comp.findall(name)[0]

        rest_name = ' '.join(comp.split(name)).strip()
        new_name = '{} {}{}'.format(date,rest_name,'.'+ext)
        print('changing {} to {}'.format(name, new_name))
        shutil.move(os.path.join(dir_path,name), os.path.join(dir_path, new_name))
    else:
        print('file {} is not change'.format(name))
```

Comment: Please mention the error as well. Is it a `FileNotFoundError` at `os.listdir(dir_path)`, or does it occur in another line?

Comment: FileNotFoundError

Comment: On which line? Just edit the question and add the exact terminal output please. The error means that some file/folder you are trying to access does not exist. So you need to pinpoint that

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with "shutil.move(os.path.join(dir_path,name), os.path.join(dir_path, new_name))". I changed to os.rename but error still occurs. It looks like this "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Testfiles\\test 2019-05-19'"

Comment: Does that file exist at that location? From your question, they were supposed to be `.txt` files right? If the path is wrong, you will need to ensure that both paths are correct for it to work (whether with shutil.move or os.rename)

Comment: Yes I have three testfiles in that folder. I noticed it puts two \\ in the error message, could that be the problem?

Comment: It probably shouldn't be, since you're on windows. A single '\' is an escape character. From what I see, `new_name` contains the file extension, but `name` does not. You need to append `ext` to `name` in order to get the correct path

Comment: What would that look like, can you give me an example what you mean?

Comment: Replace `os.path.join(dir_path,name)` with `os.path.join(dir_path,name+'.'+ext)` and see if it works